# problems at installation of sphinx on mac osx - can't even do the ./configure command

Tags: macos, installation, sphinx

I tried to install sphinx on my Mac (OSX 10.6.7) but at the first installation step, I run into a problem.

According to the installation doku, http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#installation, one should do the following steps

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ install
```

When I enter ./configure in my terminal, I get the following error message:

```
$ ./configure 
> -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

So I looked in the folder 'sphinx-2.0.1-beta-osx10.6-i386' and saw that there's no such file such as configure. Also

```
$ ls -a
> .         api         doc         sphinx-min.conf.in
  ..        bin         example.sql     sphinx.conf.in
  COPYING       contrib         log
  INSTALL       data            sphinx-min.conf
```

When I tried other files such as sphinx-min.conf, I get

```
$ ./sphinx-min.conf 
$ -bash: ./sphinx-min.conf: Permission denied
```

Also the sudo ./sphinx-min.conf doesn't work

```
$ sudo ./sphinx-min.conf 
$ sudo: ./sphinx-min.conf: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems possible that you have downloaded a binary version, rather than the source code.  You should check for binaries in the subdirectory `bin`.

You should also read the file `INSTALL`, which probably has installation instructions that go with the distribution you have downloaded.

Comment: I checked the sphinx download page -> you are right, this are the binaries. But what to do with them to get sphinx installed? 

I checked the /bin folder and get the following file: indexer  indextool search  searchd  spelldump

...and the instructions from the INSTALL file are unfortunately not really helpful: "Please refer to <<Installation>> section in doc/sphinx.txt or doc/sphinx.html."

Comment: To keep it simple, I just grabbed the source of the older version, 0.9.9, worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should download Source tarball (tar.gz) from http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/ even it has the deceptive linux-penguin icon. After decompression the tarball you can follow the installation steps as http://pat.github.com/ts/en/installing_sphinx.html says.

Comment: Can you be more precise in your answer? The link given does not give any help to the problem addressed in the question.